# how to use inner join and sub query at a time?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created 3 tables.
1st tour table 
2nd tour_details table
3rd tour_img table

Tour table

```
Create table tour(
id int identity(1,1),
unique_code varchar(10),
tour_name varchar(10)
)
```

Tour_details Table

```
Create table tour_details(
id int identity(1,1),
tour_id varchar(10),
description varchar(10)
)
```

Tour_img Table

```
Create table tour_img(
id int identity(1,1),
tour_id varchar(10),
img_path varchar(max)
)
```

Now, I want to join those three tables with the use of inner join and want only 1 row of the tour_img table

For Example

```
tour table has 1 record
id=1,
unique_code=123456
tour_name= taj mahal

Tour_details
id=1,
tour_id=123456
desc=xyz

Tour_img
id=1,
tour_id=123456
tour_img=taj_01

id=2,
tour_id=123456
tour_img=taj_2

etc...
```

So i want only one record from tour_img

I have created an query but it's not working properly.

```
select a.tour_name, 
       b.tour_desc, 
       (
           select tour_img 
           from tour_img 
           where tour_id='123456'
       ) as tour_img 
from tour a 
inner join tour_details b on a.unique_code = b.tour_id 
inner join tour_img c on a.unique_code = c.tour_id 
where a.unique_code = '123456';
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT a.tour_name,
       b.tour_desc,

  ( SELECT top 1 tour_img
   FROM tour_img
   WHERE tour_id = a.unique_code
   ORDER BY id ) AS tour_img
FROM tour a
INNER JOIN tour_details b ON a.unique_code = b.tour_id
WHERE a.unique_code = '123456';
```

No need to join tour_img to the outer query.

Comment: Thank you sir.. :)

Comment: It's Working :)

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Comment: You may want to consider the other methods here (join or cross apply). This method will result in N+1. Which if it's only one record you're OK, otherwise, might be looking for trouble

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.tour_name
     , b.tour_desc
     , c.tour_img
    from tour a 
    inner join tour_details b on a.unique_code = b.tour_id 
    inner join tour_img c on a.unique_code = c.tour_id 
    where a.unique_code = '123456';
```

Answer (score 0):

I cross apply

```
select t.tour_name, 
       td.tour_desc, 
       ti.tour_img
from   tour t 
       inner join tour_details td
               on t.unique_code = td.tour_id 
       cross apply ( select TOP 1 tour_img 
                     from   tour_img 
                     where  tour_id = t.unique_code
                     order by id ) ti
where  t.unique_code = '123456';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily solve this using `CROSS APPLY`, as such:

```
SELECT
     a.[tour_name]
    ,b.[tour_desc]
    ,c.[tour_img]
FROM [tour] AS a
INNER JOIN [tour_details] AS b
    ON a.[unique_code] = b.[tour_id]
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP 1 
     [tour_img]
  FROM [tour_img]
  WHERE [tour_id] = a.[unique_code]
  ORDER BY [tour_id] DESC
) AS c
WHERE a.[unique_code] = '12345'
;
```

This `CROSS APPLY` should give you the "last" tour_img by `tour_id`.  If you wanted the first, you could do `ORDER BY tour_img ASC` in the `CROSS APPLY`, or `ORDER BY` whichever condition you want.

You could also add something to the `WHERE` clause of the `CROSS APPLY` to get a specific row for each tour, depending on special condition.